# I can not display the exact time and date the user enters an input

Tags: python

```
import datetime
import time
x = int(input("Enter a number:")
```

I will like to make a program that show the exact time and date an user enters an input.

Comment: how do you map a number to exact time and date by the way?

Comment: Ok, so what's the problem? Do you know how to get the current time? Do you know how to print something to the console?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your code:
`print('user entered {} at {}'.format(x, datetime.datetime.now()))`

And there is a typo on line 3 - you forgot `)` at the end:
`x = int(input("Enter a number:"))`

And there's no need for `import time` statement.

Comment: But for some reasons, the datetime.datetime.now() gave me 9:56pm while my time is 5:56pm, how to get the actual time? Thank you!

Comment: This is probably because of timezone set on your OS. For example, if you are running your python script on a remote computer, `now()` will return date and time in timezone of the OS on the remote computer. So check the time in the OS first.